# Remove old files from Azure Data Lake store using PowerShell Runbook

Tags: azure-powershell

Do someone know how to delete every file which resides more than 90 days in a directory inside data lake store and sub directories?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using below code. Please check and confirm if your query is solved or not.

```
$PurgeDays = -90
$olddate = (Get-Date).AddDays($PurgeDays)


$year = (Get-Date).AddDays($PurgeDays).Year
$month = (Get-Date).AddDays($PurgeDays).Month
$day = (Get-Date).AddDays($PurgeDays).Day

Write-Output "Files older than $olddate are getting deleted..."

$path = "/MyFolder/$year/$month/$day"

$fileslist = Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreChildItem -AccountName "MyADLSAccount" -Path $path

if($fileslist)
{
    Remove-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -AccountName "MyADLSAccount" -Paths $path -Force -Recurse $true 
    Write-Output "Deleted the folder $path successfully"
}
else
{
    Write-Output "Could not purge the folder $fileslist. Either it is not old or it is not existing."
}
```